# Different labels in tooltip with chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, chart.js

I am making a radar chart with chartjs. The labels on the side of the radar I have given numbers (so the dataset Labels are numbers, 1 to 10). In the tooltip I do not want to these numbers, but a text linked to it (the text the number refers to). These are in a difrent array.

Is there a way to do this?

At the moment I have the following code:

```
$scope.drawGraph = function() {
        radarOptions = {
            scaleShowLabels : false,
            scaleFontSize: 10,
            pointLabelFontSize : 14,
            scaleBeginAtZero: true,
            showScale: true,

            scaleOverride: true,
            scaleSteps: 10,
            scaleStepWidth: 10,
            scaleStartValue: 0,

            showTooltips: true,


            customTooltips: false,
            tooltipTemplate: "<%if (datasetLabel){%><%=datasetLabel%>: <%}%><%= value + '%'%>"
        };
        var tempComp = []
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.competencesDB.length; i++) {
            tempComp.push({
                number: i + 1,
                competence: $scope.competencesDB[i]
            })

        }

        var tempLabels = [];
        var tempData = [];
        var tempName = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < tempComp.length; i++) {
            // console.log($scope.competencesDB[i])
            tempName.push(tempComp[i].competence.name)
            tempLabels.push(tempComp[i].number);
            if (tempComp[i].competence.progress.length  === 0) {
                tempData.push(0)
            } else{
                tempData.push(tempComp[i].competence.progress[tempComp[i].competence.progress.length -1].value);
            }   
        }

        radarData = {
            //names : tempName
            labels : tempLabels,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: tempName,
                    fillColor : "rgba(173, 209, 244, 0.54)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(49, 137, 225, 0.94)",
                    data : tempData
                },
                        ]
        };


        //Get the context of the Radar Chart canvas element we want to select
        var ctx = document.getElementById("radarChart").getContext("2d");

        // Create the Radar Chart
        var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(radarData, radarOptions);
    }
```

I think I need to change something in the following part:

tooltipTemplate: "<%if (datasetLabel){%><%=datasetLabel%>: <%}%><%= value + '%'%>"

But I don't know how this part of the code works. Can I but some kind of forloop in this to loop through the second datasetLabel part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a function instead of a template string. As you guessed you need to figure out the `name` from the `number`.

Here is a generic sample

```
var numberNames = [
    { number: 1, name: "Eating" },
    { number: 2, name: "Drinking" },
    { number: 3, name: "Sleeping" },
    { number: 4, name: "Designing" },
    { number: 8, name: "Coding" },
    { number: 9, name: "Cycling" },
    { number: 10, name: "Running" }
];


var data = {
    labels: numberNames.map(function(e) { return e.number }),
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 9, 10, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, {
    tooltipTemplate: function (valueObject) {
        return numberNames.filter(function (e) { return e.number === valueObject.label })[0].name + ': ' + valueObject.value;
    }
});
```

I used `numberNames` but you should be able to replace that with `tempComp` (after adjusting the `labels` property and the tooltipTemplate function body slightly).

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/80wdhbwo/